# Redirect from index.html to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have entered this code in .htaccess and it gives me the error "bad flag delimiters" and the website is unreacheable after this code (it give error 500 internal server error).

Anybody knows what is wrong with this code?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\.html$
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ https://www.kamagra-uzitek.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.html $
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1\.html [END]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Take a look into your http server's error log file. There you can _read_ what the issue is.

Comment: It tells me "bad flag delimiters" but i still dont know what is wrong, thats why i came here, hoping i would get some help.

Comment: Could it be that you operate a very old version of the apache http server that does not yet implement the `END` flag?

Comment: I think that it is not possible, i have a server at the best company in a country. Do you maybe have any idea if there is something wrong with the code i have pasted?

Comment: Good company or not, the version of the server is relevant. Did you check it? No? Why not?

Comment: This line is invalid, as far as I can tell: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.html $`... The blank before the `$` has to be removed.

Comment: Thank you! You were right, i have fixed it and now it doesnt show that the website is unavailable, but it still doesnt redirect from https://www.kamagra-uzitek.com/index.html to https://www.kamagra-uzitek.com